# Manually Created ID throws Multiple Representations of the Same Entity Error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a backend application which is behind an API gateway. Both of them are Spring Boot applications. There is a location service at backend which stores a city id (UUID) and and name.

API Gateway queries cities and store them at Address entity which has a city field. I have created the city entity at API gateway as follows:

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My address entity has:

```
@NotNull
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private City city;
```

I want to have same UUIDs as id with backend db. However, I cannot save two different addresses with same city UUIDs. I get that error:

> Multiple representations of the same entity [..] are being merged

I've tried to change CascadeType.ALL to all other cascedes apart from CascadeType.MERGE but still get error.

Any ideas?